# JQuery Mixitup Elements through AngularJS ngrepeating not working

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I've been working on this last two days and didn't figure out where is the mistake I've done.

Trying to repeat elements by Angular from json source and its successfully repeating the content. 
But after that needs to be apply Mixitup plugin.

### Here is Angular code:

```
$scope.url = 'views/portfolio-all.php';
    $http.post($scope.url).
    success(function(data, status) {
    if ( angular.isArray(data) ) {
        $scope.reports = data;
    }
    else {
        $scope.reports = [data];
    }           
    })
    .
    error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = status;
        console.log(status);
    }); 
    $('#portfolioList').mixItUp({
    callbacks: {
        onMixLoad: function(){
            console.log('MixItUp ready!');
        },
        onMixFail: function(){
            console.log("No elements found matching");
        }
    },
    load: {
        filter: '.website'
    },
    debug: {
        enable: true,
        mode: 'verbose'
    }
});
```

---

This is my html, do you see mistakes?

```
<div id="portfolio-thumbs">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="menubar controls">
        <ul>
            <li class="filter hide" data-filter="all">Show All</li>
            <li class="filter active" data-filter=".website">Websites</li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".mobile">Mobiles</li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".brand">Brand & Identity</li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".ecommerce">E-Commerce</li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".print">Print & Graphics</li>
            <li class="filter" data-filter=".marketing">Marketing</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="controls hide">
        <ul>
            <li class="sort" data-sort="data-cat" data-order="desc">Descending</li>
            <li class="sort" data-sort="data-cat" data-order="asc">Ascending</li>
            <li class="sort active" data-sort="default" data-order="desc">Default</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="portfolioList" ng:repeat="report in reports">

          <div class="mix {{reportItem.categories}}"  ng:repeat="reportItem in report">
            <a ng-href="#portfolio/{{reportItem.title_alias}}">
                <img ng-src="{{reportItem.img}}"/>
                <div><span>{{reportItem.title}}</span></div>
            </a>
           </div>

        <div class="gap"></div>
        <div class="gap"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there isn't enough info here to help you. Please indicate any errors from your console, include the view/template that is relevant, and be sure you have included jquery before angular.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your problem, however you want to activate mixItUp after the request is complete you will need to call it from the success callback as the calls are asynchronous.

```
$scope.url = 'views/portfolio-all.php';
    $http.post($scope.url).
    success(function(data, status) {
    if ( angular.isArray(data) ) {
        $scope.reports = data;
    }
    else {
        $scope.reports = [data];
    }

    //call mixItUpHere:
    $('#portfolioList').mixItUp({
    callbacks: {
        onMixLoad: function(){
            console.log('MixItUp ready!');
        },
        onMixFail: function(){
            console.log("No elements found matching");
        }
    },
    load: {
        filter: '.website'
    },
    debug: {
        enable: true,
        mode: 'verbose'
    }           
    })
    error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || "Request failed";
        $scope.status = status;
        console.log(status);
    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two potential problems here.

The first one is that `$http` is async so you might need to run any sort of initialization inside your $http().success callback.

```
$http.get('myurl.php').success(function(data){
   //do stuff here that deals with your returned data
});
```

The second one needs a bit more of an explanation:

Modifying the DOM outside of angular context is typically not something you want to do (because of how angular runtime works).

Just because you assign an array to your $scope variable doesn't mean the DOM nodes have been created (through ng-repeat, etc). Often times you'll have to force angular to "refresh itself" and run digest loop triggered by certain methods. The typical one is $scope.$apply, you can find information on this sort of thing here:

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

I myself typically use the $timeout service which also takes care of this internally. So I would just wrap your jQuery plugin code with:

```
$timeout(function() {
    // load jquery plugin here
    // at 500ms so you can tell for sure if this is the problem or not
    // normally you wouldn't want to wait a half second to load something
}, 500);
```

Disclaimer:
Fixing non deterministic code with timeout() or sleep() mechanisms is a really bad idea most of the time unless you really need to hack something together.

I would try out `$scope.$apply()` as well or move the `$timeout` time to 1ms or something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

When I putting the mixitup in success state, its not even calling it from there but when I put it in actual html that renders ng-repeat, its calling and it gives me following debug message.

- [MixItUp][portfolioList][_bindHandlers] 3 sort buttons found.
- [MixItUp][portfolioList][_bindHandlers] 7 filter buttons found.
- [MixItUp][portfolioList][_init] MixItUp instantiated on container with ID "portfolioList".
- [MixItUp][portfolioList][_init] There are currently 1 instances of MixItUp in the document.
- [MixItUp][portfolioList][_refresh] MixItUp refreshed. 0 targets were 
  found and indexed. No elements found matching VM1214:8 MixItUp ready!
- VM1214:5 [MixItUp][portfolioList][_cleanUp] Loading animation completed successfully.

Comment: Sorry for mess in above,